# GetDIBBits SetDIBBits

Tags: gdi

When call GetDIBBits?

Does in return reverse ordered lines of a bitmap in buffer or direct?

Answer (score 0):

DIBs are always in reverse order unless you create them with negative height

Comment: Then when call SetDIBBits the API doesn't reverse it? Or it will reverse in direct order? Then if we apply BitBlt - then will it reverse? When I get DC from bitmap handle then would it make any reverse operations?

Comment: There is no reversing happening just DIBs are always stored upside-down, i.e. scan0 is the bottom - unless you create it with negative height.

Comment: When call GetDIBBits: does it create a new reversed array or just passes reference to actual data?

Comment: It copies the data, try passing negative height to GetDIBits if you want it flipped

Comment: Do you mean cScanLines parameter?

int GetDIBits(
  __in     HDC hdc,
  __in     HBITMAP hbmp,
  __in     UINT uStartScan,
  __in     UINT cScanLines,
  __out    LPVOID lpvBits,
  __inout  LPBITMAPINFO lpbi,
  __in     UINT uUsage
);